# Python Text based adventure game adding/getting items

Tags: python

Hey guys im doing the Python texted based game and i can't figure out how to get an item from the room and add it to the inventory. i have the rooms defined and the inventory defined, but i cant write a proper call or command to get and add the items from specific rooms to the inventory. let me know if you can see something im missing or can add please!

```
rooms = {'Vestibule': {'name': 'the Vestibule', 'go East': 'Great Hall', 'item': 'none'},
     'Great Hall': {'name': 'the Great Hall', 'go North': 'Common Room', 'go East': 'Study',
                    'go South': 'Kitchen', 'go West': 'Vestibule', 'item': 'Wand'},
     'Common Room': {'name': 'the Common Room', 'go East': 'Laboratory', 'go South': 'Great Hall', 'item': 'Map'},
     'Laboratory': {'name': 'the Laboratory', 'go West': 'Common Room', 'item': 'Potion'},
     'Kitchen': {'name': 'the Kitchen', 'go North': 'Great Hall', 'go East': 'Dungeon', 'item': 'Chocolate Frog'},
     'Dungeon': {'name': 'the Dungeon', 'go West': 'Kitchen', 'item': 'Slug Repellent'},
     'Study': {'name': 'the Study', 'go North': 'Observation Tower',
               'go West': 'Great Hall', 'item': 'Invisibility Cloak'},
     'Observation Tower': {'name': 'the Observation Tower', 'go South': 'Study', 'item': 'Evil Wizard'}}

print('Wizard Text Adventure Game\n')
print('Collect 6 items to win the game, or be defeated by the Evil Wizard.')
print('Move commands: go South, go North, go East, go West')
print('Add to Inventory: get item')

current_room = rooms['Vestibule']
directions = ['go North', 'go South', 'go East', 'go West']
Item = ['Wand', 'Map', 'Potion', 'Chocolate Frog', 'Slug Repellent', 'Invisibility Cloak']
Inventory = {}

while True:
    print('-' * 30)
    print('You are in the {}'.format(current_room['name']))
    print('Your current inventory: {}\n'.format(Inventory))
    if current_room['item']:
        print('Item in room: {}'.format(''.join(current_room['item'])))
        print('')

command = input('Enter your move: \n')
if command in directions:
    if command in current_room:
        current_room = rooms[current_room[command]]
        if current_room['name'] == 'Observation Tower':
            print('Congratulations! You have reached the Observation Tower and defeated the Evil Wizard!')
            break
    else:
        print('\nChoose another path.')

elif command == 'quit':
    print('Thanks for playing!')
    break

else:
    print('Invalid input')
```

Comment: You should keep track of game objects as their own classes, and have one instance of each object existing in the world. You just are using text to keep track of the objects in separate places which is not ideal in my opinion. So, you instantiate the objects, then insert them into the rooms. Also, the rooms should also be their own classes, in my opinion, so they can have a property like `self.items_list = []`, where you can insert the item objects. Just throwing those ideas out there, maybe that'll help get you unstuck?

Answer (score 0):

Check the code and see if this is what you are looking for(Does it solve your problem? PS: the code might break due to formating errors when copying from the idle to stack overflow.. be sure to fix the indentations if any errors come up): I also suggest creating classes for each room to hold individual data as it makes the program logic much more clearer...

```
rooms = {'Vestibule': {'name': 'the Vestibule', 'go East': 'Great Hall', 'item': 'none'},
     'Great Hall': {'name': 'the Great Hall', 'go North': 'Common Room', 'go East': 'Study',
                    'go South': 'Kitchen', 'go West': 'Vestibule', 'item': 'Wand'},
     'Common Room': {'name': 'the Common Room', 'go East': 'Laboratory', 'go South': 'Great Hall', 'item': 'Map'},
     'Laboratory': {'name': 'the Laboratory', 'go West': 'Common Room', 'item': 'Potion'},
     'Kitchen': {'name': 'the Kitchen', 'go North': 'Great Hall', 'go East': 'Dungeon', 'item': 'Chocolate Frog'},
     'Dungeon': {'name': 'the Dungeon', 'go West': 'Kitchen', 'item': 'Slug Repellent'},
     'Study': {'name': 'the Study', 'go North': 'Observation Tower',
               'go West': 'Great Hall', 'item': 'Invisibility Cloak'},
     'Observation Tower': {'name': 'the Observation Tower', 'go South': 'Study', 'item': 'Evil Wizard'}}

print('Wizard Text Adventure Game\n')
print('Collect 6 items to win the game, or be defeated by the Evil Wizard.')
print('Move commands: go South, go North, go East, go West')
print('Add to Inventory: get item')

current_room = rooms['Vestibule']
directions = ['go North', 'go South', 'go East', 'go West']
Item = ['Wand', 'Map', 'Potion', 'Chocolate Frog', 'Slug Repellent', 'Invisibility Cloak']
Inventory = {}
#Inventory = []

while True:
    print('-' * 30)
    print('You are in the {}'.format(current_room['name']))
    print('Your current inventory: {}\n'.format(Inventory))
    if current_room['item']:
        print('Item in room: {}'.format(''.join(current_room['item'])))
        print('')

    command = input('Enter your move: \n')
    
    if command in directions:
        if command in current_room:
            current_room = rooms[current_room[command]]
            if current_room['name'] == 'Observation Tower':
                print('Congratulations! You have reached the Observation Tower and defeated the Evil Wizard!')
                break
        else:
            print('\nChoose another path.')
    elif command == 'get item':
        if current_room['item'] != 'none':
            Inventory['Item' + str(len(Inventory.keys()) + 1)] =  current_room['item']
            #Inventory.append(current_room['item'])
 
            print("You aquired : " ,current_room['item'] )
            print(Inventory)
            current_room['item'] = 'none'
        else:
            print("No items to collect in this room")
            

    elif command == 'quit':
        print('Thanks for playing!')
        break

    else:
        print('Invalid input')
```

Comment: Ankan! thank for your help, its so close to what i need. I need the inventory to stack, right now the output is {item1:"item"} for whichever room im currently in.  I need to be able to add all items to inventory as im collecting them.

Comment: @Tybomb21 maybe you should use `list` instead of `dictionary` to keep `Inventory` - and then you can do `Inventory.append(  current_room['item'] )` and it will keep all items. With dictionary you would have to use some value to increase number in `item1`, `item2`, `item3`, etc.

Comment: @Tybomb21 and don't forget to remove item from room ie. `current_room['item'] = "none"`

Comment: I fixed the code and now it stores item number correctly and also removes items from the room after collecting them..... But I agree with @furas that it would be better to store the items in an Inventory LIST ..... so i added the list statements as comments..